# How to update a quantity in another document when creating a new document in the firebase firestore collection?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

When I create a new document in the note collection, I want to update the quantity in the info document. What am I doing wrong?

```
exports.addNote = functions.region('europe-west1').firestore
  .collection('users/{userId}/notes').onCreate((snap,context) => {
    const uid = admin.user.uid.toString();
    var t;
  db.collection('users').doc('{userId}').collection('info').doc('info').get((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      t = doc.get("countMutable").toString();
    });
  });
  let data = {
    countMutable: t+1;
  };
  db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("info").doc("info").update({countMutable: data.get("countMutable")});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have... a lot going on here.  A few problems:

- You can't trigger firestore functions on collections, you have to supply a document.
- It isn't clear you're being consistent about how to treat the user id.
- You aren't [using promises properly](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) (you need to chain them, and return them out of the function if you want them to execute properly).
- I'm not clear about the relationship between the `userId` context parameter and the `uid` you are getting from the auth object.  As far as I can tell, `admin.user` isn't actually part of the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node).
- You risk multiple function calls doing an increment at the same time giving inconsistent results, since you aren't using a transaction or the `increment` operation.  ([Learn More Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value))
- The document won't be created if it doesn't already exist.  Maybe this is ok?

In short, this all means you can do this a lot more simply.

This should do you though.  I'm assuming that the `uid` you actually want is actually the one on the document that is triggering the update.  If not, adjust as necessary.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.addNote = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}/notes/{noteId}').onCreate((snap,context) => {
    const uid = context.params.userId;
    return db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("info").doc("info").set({
      countMutable: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    }, { merge: true });
});
```

If you don't want to create the `info` document if it doesn't exist, and instead you want to get an error, you can use `update` instead of `set`:

```js
    return db.collection("users").doc(uid).collection("info").doc("info").update({
      countMutable: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    });
```